# rotate transform producing jagged text

Tags: css

I have a div formatted to look like a sticky note ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/srp2e/1/)). Looking at it in Firefox and Safari, the text looks all nasty and jagged. It's somewhat better in Chrome, but not much. Is there anything I can do about this, or should I just give up my dreams of beautifully laid out stickies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the browsers just have a hard time rendering small text with small angles. If you increase the font size, you will see that the text renders a little bit more clearly. Really, the 90 degree angles are the only ones that cleanly render on most sizes of fonts.

Comment: You're right, it actually looks pretty good at huge font sizes.